# Passing arguments to another script, after having used the "shift" builtin

Tags: bash

Consider a simple script `program.sh`:

```
$ cat program.sh
echo program: I have "$#" arguments, they are "$@"
$ ./program.sh 1 2 3
program: I have 3 arguments, they are 1 2 3
$ ./program.sh '1 1' 2 3
program: I have 3 arguments. they are 1 1 2 3
```

Now I want a wrapper script `wrapper.sh` that invokes `program.sh` in the same way it was invoked:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
echo wrapper: I have "$#" arguments, they are "$@"
./program.sh "$@"
$ ./wrapper.sh 1 2 3
wrapper: I have 3 arguments, they are 1 2 3
program: I have 3 arguments, they are 1 2 3
$ ./wrapper.sh '1 1' 2 3
wrapper: I have 3 arguments. they are 1 1 2 3
program: I have 3 arguments. they are 1 1 2 3
```

This works perfectly, but I want to use the `shift` builtin within `wrapper.sh`, which creates a problem because then I cannot use `"$@"` anymore in the invocation to `program.sh`:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
echo wrapper: I have "$#" arguments, they are "$@"
shift
./program.sh "$@"
$ ./wrapper.sh 1 2 3
wrapper: I have 3 arguments, they are 1 2 3
program: I have 2 arguments, they are 2 3
$ ./wrapper.sh '1 1' 2 3
wrapper: I have 3 arguments. they are 1 1 2 3
program: I have 2 arguments. they are 2 3
```

I have tried initially setting the value of `$@` to a temporary variable, but nothing I tried seems to work for `wrapper.sh` to invoke `program.sh` exactly the way it was originally invoked. What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to save `$@`.  Just save it as an array:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh 
echo wrapper: I have "$#" arguments, they are "$@"
save=("$@")
shift
./program.sh "${save[@]}"
```

This produces the output:

```
$ wrapper.sh '1 1' 2 3
wrapper: I have 3 arguments, they are 1 1 2 3
program: I have 3 arguments, they are 1 1 2 3
```

The key here is that `save` is a bash array.  Trying to store `$@` as a shell string does not work.  Saving it as an array does work.